# json get name which id matches

Tags: json, angularjs

i am working on a small app in angularJS and i have 2 json lists, 1 is called `jsonPartners` and the other one is called `jsonServices`.

I have a table with a select box inside my app that shows the partners names inside it and it is default selected to the partner name which id is inside each jsonService item like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="service in jsonServices">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td><select ng-model="service.partner_id" ng-options="partner.id as partner.name for partner in jsonPartners"></select></td>
</tr>
```

Now this works great, and the default name is selected correct but somewhere else in the app i have to add this name from jsonPartners based on the partner_id which matches with the partner_id from jsonServices.

This is how the jsonService and jsonPartners looks like

```
jsonServices = [{'partner_id':'5'}, {''partner_id':'7'}];

jsonPartners = [{'partner_id':'5','partner_name':'Dany'}, {''partner_id':'7', 'partner_name':'Andreea'}];
```

Is there a way to do that ? Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: Can this be done? Certainly.... it's just not clear exactly what you need....  update the array and add properties, have lookup for html output, change on an event etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular filters like

`$filter('filter')(jsonPartners, {'partner_id':selectedPartnerId})[0]`

The final result is an array. See documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter